# How can I stop boost dynamic links from being added into my application?

Tags: macos, boost, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have a dylib project that is statically linked against two boost artifacts (filesystem.a and system.a) but when I run `otool -L mylib.dylib` the output says that it depends on the .dylib versions of those two.  If I move the boost dylibs out of the path after building, then the application fails to run.  However, if I move them out of the path and *then* build, then the dependencies disappear and the app runs just fine.  What settings do I need to add to stop these dynamic dependencies from being inserted into my project?

I tried adding the `-static` flag but I got more linker errors, and after I fixed them the dependencies were still there anyway.  Also preprocessor macros like `BOOST_USE_NO_LIB` had no  effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found one way, but I'm not sure if it is the best.  The linker Xcode uses seems to prefer dynamic libraries if they are found, and there doesn't seem to be an easy way to add an option to override this.  However, if I erase the link in the build phases tab and add the full path to the static libraries manually in the other linker flags, then it works as expected.  However, if there is another way I would like to hear it.